# How to get all input having the same class, id name in Controller - Laravel 5?

Tags: input, laravel-5

I have function which appends new answer inputs when 'Add answer' button is clicked. In Controller, i want to get the value of all answer inputs with id or class.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
<script>
var txt1 = '{!! Form::text('answer1',null,['class' => 'answer']) !!}';
$(document).on('click','#btn1',function(){
                  $(this).before(txt1);
            });
</script>
```

In Controller, I'm using this:

```
$input['answer_body'] = Input::get('answer1');
```

I can get one value according to one id in Laravel, but now i need to get all values that have same id and class.

Could anybody help me?

Comment: You can't use an ID on more than one element, IDs are meant to be unique. That's how HTML is designed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, the ID and class aren't submitted and so aren't available in the PHP. What you can do is get results by the same name by turning them into an array. Change `Form::text('answer1',` to `Form::text('answer1[]'` so that you can submit multiple inputs with the same name.

If you then use `$input['answer_body'] = Input::get('answer1');`, `$input['answer_body']` will have an array in it. You can get specific answers by using dot notation to specify which input you want to get, e.g.: `Input::get('answer1.0');` will fetch the value in the first input with a name of `answer1[]`.